# Retrieving multiple sub queries output with different rows into a single response in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to receive the output of a few sub queries(each of them return a single column with different number of rows) into a single response.

I'm trying the following but it doesn't work with error as `[21000] ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT DISTINCT org_name
   FROM table_1
   WHERE column1= 1)                        AS terminal_1,
  (SELECT org_name
   FROM table_5
   WHERE column5= 1)                          AS cfs_1,
  (SELECT DISTINCT org_name
   FROM table_4 where column7= 136 )     AS terminals_2,
  (SELECT org_name
   FROM table_6
   WHERE column1=7)                           AS cfs_2;
```

I'd like to do in the way such that in future I can add a few more sub-queries, each of which will also return a single column with a different number of rows. Is there a good practice to achieve the same? Thank you.

EDIT 1: The output response could be in any logical form. i.e. tabular or JSON.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) 3 tables are enough.

Comment: You can't use a query in the SELECT list that returns more then one row. Either include the PK in the `WHERE` clause or use `LIMIT 1` to make sure only a single row is returned

Comment: (Cont. from our nameless equine friend) Or use an aggregating function on the sub-query return, such as string_agg or array_agg.

Comment: @jarlh The expected result could be in any logical form. I just need to make sure that I can segregate the result of each sub query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about making us of PostgreSQL's excellent [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html)?

```
with terminal_1 as (
  SELECT array_agg (DISTINCT org_name) as term1_name
  FROM table_1
  WHERE column1= 1
),
cfs_1 as (
  SELECT array_agg (org_name) as cfs1_name
  FROM table_5
  WHERE column5= 1
),
terminals_2 as (
  SELECT array_agg (DISTINCT org_name) as term2_name
  FROM table_4 where column7= 136
),
cfs_2 as (
  SELECT array_agg (org_name) as cfs2_name
  FROM table_6
  WHERE column1=7
)
select
  term1_name, cfs1_name, term2_name, cfs2_name
from
  terminal_1
  cross join cfs_1
  cross join terminals_2
  cross join cfs_2
```

While this doesn't perform the cosmetics of what you want, I believe it does deliver the content the way you intended.

Comment: Yes, It does deliver it the way I expected. Thanks. Should I worry too much about the execution time?

Comment: If that's a reasonably good representation of your actual query then I don't know there is a lot you can do about performance...  I assume you run them in isolation, and they take about the same amount of time?  If don't already have indexes for the columns referenced, add them and see if it helps, and bear in mind `distinct` is a performance killer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you simply need `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT DISTINCT  't1' tableNum, org_name
FROM table_1
WHERE column1= 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 't5' tableNum, org_name
FROM table_5
WHERE column5= 1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 't4' tableNum, org_name
FROM table_4 
where column7= 136
UNION ALL
SELECT 't6' tableNum, org_name
FROM table_6
WHERE column1=7
```

Comment: This will join all the rows. I need to keep the result of each sub query different from another one.

Comment: @AnandTyagi Ok, and if you add an extra column that will differentiate the results as it is now in the edited answer?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, I have overlooked it when editing